# File open dialog in ImageJ Javascript Script

Tags: javascript, dialog, macros, imagej, imagej-macro

I want to write a macro/script to open a file open dialog, and then import the selected image using BF with various options.

I found this JS script for doing the latter part [here](http://imagej.net/Scripting_toolbox#Macro_2):

```
importClass(Packages.loci.plugins.BF);
importClass(Packages['loci.plugins.in.ImporterOptions']); // 'in' is a reserved word, hence the different syntax
importClass(Packages.loci.common.Region);

var path = "/path/to/file";
var options = new ImporterOptions();
options.setId(path);
options.setAutoscale(true);
options.setCrop(true);
options.setCropRegion(0, new Region(x, y, w. h));
options.setColorMode(ImporterOptions.COLOR_MODE_COMPOSITE);
var imps = BF.openImagePlus(options);

imps[0].show();
```

I also found the regular macro language file open dialog [here](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#F):

```
File.openDialog(title)
```

How do I do both of these things in a JS script? Specifically, how do I create the file open dialog in JS?

If it is easier to do both in the macro IJM language, rather than Javascript, then how do I create a BF object and set the import options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the ImageJ macro functions are implemented in `ij.macro.Functions`, so you can find what you need in [`Functions.java`](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/master/src/main/java/ij/macro/Functions.java#L3862-L3871)

- From **Javascript**, you can use `ij.io.OpenDialog`:

  ```
  importClass(Packages.ij.io.OpenDialog);

  od = OpenDialog("Choose a file", null);
  folder = od.getDirectory();
  file = od.getFileName();
  path = folder + file;
  ```
- Alternatively, you can use the option string of the *Bio-Formats Importer* **macro** command, it's all in the [macro you linked to](http://imagej.net/Scripting_toolbox#Macro_2):

  ```
  run("Bio-Formats Importer", "open=" + path + "autoscale color_mode=Default view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT");
  ```

  To get the required options, simply use the [macro recorder](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#The_recorder).